# Can not stop fusedLocation updates using removeLocationUpdates

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have created a class naming **MyLocationProvider** with all methods provided in [fusedLocationAPI](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-update) as well as the following to stop the location updates:

```
private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}
```

In main activity I use this class like this:

```
MyLocationProvider mylocation=new MyLocationProvider(this);
```

Location updates works fine but I am confused how [requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#updates) works. When I close then application, `requestLocationUpdates` is not stopped (it seem something like background process but is not listed in device services). When I open the application, a new instance of `MyLocationProvider` also starts working and I receive multiple parallel updates from my device.

How should I use `removeLocationUpdates` to stop an exact instance of location provider when they seems not to be a part of my application?

Comment: When u have called this stop method ??

Comment: I don't know how to use this method. I loose the created instance of `MyLocationProvider` when I close the app. How can I access it later? @Md.ibrahimkhalil

Comment: Sorry for late.please see the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on stop or on destroy method of fragment or activity which is used by u.

Comment: How can I access `mylocation` which I have created in previous run? In fact `MyLocationProvider mylocation=new MyLocationProvider(this);` runs a new instance of Location service every time I open the app.

Comment: Make it global then access it from onstop or On destroy